# Cannot find any tns-core-module/ui Modules NativeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript

I am writing a {N}-Application and need to import Images from the `tns-core-modules/ui/image`-module. Sadly he says that he cannot find that target in the tns-core-module.

My code:

```
import * as ImageModule from "tns-core-module/ui/image";
```

What am I supposed to do now? How can I fix this?

My `npm --version`: `3.10.10`

My `node -v`: `v6.11.1`

My TS-Version: 2.4.2

The `tns-core-modules` are `Version 2.2.1` in my package.json

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the path you provided is valid? It seems like you want to reference it relatively, but you might have to go up a few levels if you are. For instance:

```
import * as ImageModule from "../tns-core-module/ui/image"; //This will go up two levels.
```

Alternatively, you may be able to import the module using a path declared in your tsconfig.json file. Something along the lines of

```
        "paths": {
        "*": [
            "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*"
        ]
    }
```

If that's the case, you can simply import by using

```
imprt * as ImageModule from "ui/images";
```