# Unknown compiler option ''paths' when trying to execute NativeScript Application

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, nativescript

I want to access the ui-elements of the tns-core-modules. Since I have been struggling a little with this I did some research and find out, that I might have to add the following lines to my tsconfig.json:

```
    "paths": {
        "*": [
        "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
        "./node_modules/*"]
    }
```

Now I keep getting the following error:

> error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'paths'.

My tsconfig file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "paths": {
            "*": [
            "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
            "./node_modules/*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "platforms"
    ]
}
```

My package.json:

```
    //some stuff
    "nativescript-telerik-ui": "1.3.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "2.2.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    //some stuff
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "0.3.2",
    "typescript": "1.8.10"
  }
```

Does someone have a clue what might be going wrong?

Comment: You are using a pretty old version of tns-core-modules (and I guess of NativeScript CLI and runtimes) and old version of TypeScript. If updating to latest is not an option (where the setup of your `tsconfig.json` should work as expected) you can try to simply remove the paths and the CLI should handle the paths by itself - e.g. here is an old project using tns-core-modules 2.4.1 https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/blob/master/NativeScript/issue_3426/tsconfig.json

Comment: Sadly because of a lot of the modules in the package.json an upgrade to the latest version is not an option. I am not getting an error when declining the import, but when compiling it. (compare [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814066/cannot-find-any-tns-core-module-ui-modules-nativescript)). Thanks for the answer though, I guess I have no other choice than removing them :)

Comment: even without setting `paths` the direct import should work as done here: https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/blob/master/NativeScript/issue_3426/app/main-page.ts#L2